# Can't import into Swift bridging header Objective-C file that imports Project-Swift.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to #import an Objective-C class to my Project-Bridging-Header.h.
The problem is that the same class has an #import to my "Project-Swift.h" file.
So - I'm getting a compilation error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you have a dependency cycle. Can you use @class directives?

Comment: Same issue here. Cannot use @class as I have `enum` definitions in Swift, and the ObjC header file needs that enum in its declaration. And the ObjC header file needs to be in the bridging header.

Comment: @fabb Did you find a solution for this? Or is it not solvable?

Comment: You are not allowed to import the "Project-Swift.h" in your class header files. The only time this is a problem is with enums. So all enums that are contained in method signatures from objc class headers need to be written in objc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a forward declaration of the enum:

`enum myEnum;`

But this [doesn't get you very much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35066261/5099014). The prevailing wisdom is to define any cross language enums in an Ojective-C context.