# How to reference Swift enum in Objective-C Header

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a way to reference a Swift enum from an Objective-C header? If you want to see Swift classes in the Objective-C header you can use

```
@objc class Foo
```

I don't see anything similar for enums.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want to do is called `forward declaration`. To forward declare an enum you can do:

```
enum name;
```

But since the compiler won't know the size of the enum, you will only be able to use it as a pointer in your header file.
Even doing this might prove problematic if you use compiler flags like `-pedantic`.

So in short, there is no good way to do this. Your best bet is not to, and access the enum from your implementation (.m) file instead.

In your implementation file, `#import` your swift bridging header file, and, without knowing more details about your problem, you could add private properties that use your enum like this:

```
@interface MyObjCClassDefinedInTheHFile()
    @property (nonatomic, assign) SomeSwiftEnum type;
@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agree that no good answer. The codebase I'm working on is in flux between Swift and Objective C, so my solution here was to declare the enum in a (somewhat) appropriate objc file instead, until we're fully on Swift. It's much simpler to share enums between objc and swift that way, using the bridging header file.

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately that might be your best bet, especially if the enum needs to have that much visibility within your project.

Comment: Forward declaring works : `typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);`

Comment: Try `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);` for forward declaration.

Comment: Does anyone know why `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);` is working for me, but `typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);` isn't?

Comment: @ArielSD it seems that `SWIFT_ENUM` requires a third argument now, something called `extensibility`

Answer (score 19):

`typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);`

Comment: Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Try `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum);` as suggested by @zh

Answer (score 3):

In Mixed OBJC - Swift projects the best way to have enums work in both types of classes will be to define the enum in an OBJC header and not in a swift class. swift enums can't be used in OBJC header files
taken from the answer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25506)

Answer (score 2):

enums are one part of the swift Objective-C communication that does not always work. The thing is that in Objective-C, the enums can just be primitive types(`NSInteger` for example).

In `swift` you can have enums on more types, for example like `String`. Which is one of the awesome things about swift.

However, these enums wont be compiled to Objective-C because there is no equivalent for them. So they will simply be ignore and not generated in this header file that xcode creates for all your swift files. 
This is called Objective-C generated interface header:
[image]

This generated file contains all the classes and enums available in objective-c . You have to mark everything you want to expose in Objective-c with `@objc` or make them `public`. You dont need any forward declaration for them to work, if you have this.

Hope this helps you figure out why your enum is not visible in Objc. Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: In my swift project I have enum with custom type(assume Test(name, address)). Is there any way to expose those enums as cutom type/class to object c?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, [raf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35066261/813247) is still correct. The cleanest solution is to simply leave your enum in an Objective-C file until you no longer need to access it from an Objective-C header. I wanted to offer another possible workaround, though.

In my case I am gradually rewriting a large Objective-C project in Swift, and I don't mind an imperfect workaround if it allows me to rewrite more of my code in Swift. So I've settled on simply passing the enum to Objective-C as it's raw type, `Int`, or `NSInteger` to Objective-C. For example:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithType:(NSInteger)rawType {
    if (rawType == ExampleTypeWhatever) {
        // Do something
    } // etc...
}
```

When I call this method from Swift, all I have to do is pass the `.rawValue`, instead of the actual enum value:

```
objcObject.doSomething(withType: ExampleType.whatever.rawValue)
```

This keeps things fairly simple on both sides, and it'll be easy to update once `doSomethingWithType:` is eventually rewritten in Swift.

Answer (score -2):

I just use `NSInteger` as return type for both header and implementation files. And when you need to use the enum, get the enum by `let yourEnum = YourEnum(rawValue: Int(enumNSInteger))`. This works for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can access Swift enums in Objective-C, but *only* if the enum is declared with an `@objc` qualifier, which means that it has to be of type `Int`.

Comment: Right and I've done that. That won't make it available in the header tho.

Comment: Your Obj-C header has to `#include "<your-project-name>-Swift.h"`. Is that what you need?

Comment: You can't include the -Swift.h file in an Objective-C header file. You can only include it in an implementation file.

Comment: "You can't include the -Swift.h file in an Objective-C header file. You can only include it in an implementation file." @Phil: Really? Why not?

Comment: I was basing that off of https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122. "Import the Swift code from that target into any Objective-C .m file within that target using this syntax and substituting the appropriate name:" Perhaps I am wrong and it does work. I have compile errors when trying to do that tho.

Comment: Also, there is this on that page, "To avoid cyclical references, don’t import Swift code into an Objective-C header (.h) file. Instead, you can forward declare a Swift class or protocol to reference it in an Objective-C interface."

Comment: The problem happens when you try to make an Objective-C class extend a Swift one, if your Swift bridging header includes and Obj-C includes (and why wouldn't it?). If that's the case, then you can't just declare a forward reference to the Swift class.

Comment: @Phil I see "forward declare" thrown around a lot, but I'm not sure what it is. Got a link or an explanation?